# how to find first and last record from mysql table only for todays record?

Tags: mysql

I have to find very first record of today and last record of current day(now).How to get that?

Comment: Does your table contain a DATETIME or DATE or TIME column ? 
What do you mean when you say "today"? Rows whose timestamp is today? Or rows that have been added today?

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: agree with @Strawberry, there nothing this question has which deserves upvotes

Comment: timestamp is today

Answer (score 2):

To get both lines in a single query, assuming that your date column is a `DATE`field, you will do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` = CURDATE() ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) tb1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` = CURDATE() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) tb2
```

*Note that this example may not be good / optimal if your column type is something else or have the dates saved in a different format. But you did not specified that.*

Comment: The  union don't allow two separated  order by  .. but one only.. so you should laborate you query a bit more

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, you are right. I missed that. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Due the fact that is not possibile order by the union select in different way you can override this limit using select from dinamic selected tables this way

```
  select * from 
  ( SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` = CURDATE() ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) t1 
  UNION
  select * from 
  ( SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` = CURDATE() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT a.*
        FROM
        (
                SELECT MIN(ID)
                FROM your_table
                WHERE date_column BETWEEN  '2016-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-25 23:59:59'
                UNION
                SELECT MAX(ID)
                FROM your_table
                WHERE date_column BETWEEN  '2016-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-25 23:59:59'
        )a
);
```